# Missing iterations in loop under SLURM

Tags: bash, slurm, sbatch

I have a simple code that iterates through a file and do some simple calculus. The code that follows is an excerpt of a biggest one: don't ask for any utility in this code, it is just a minimal example of the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --output=test_%j.out
#SBATCH --error=test_%j.err
#SBATCH --workdir=.
#SBATCH --time=0:5:0
#SBATCH --partition=main
#SBATCH --qos=lowprio
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --requeue

for SM in MB BL
do
    while read -r id
    do
        srun --job-name "Test-${id}" --nodes 1 --ntasks 1 --cpus-per-task 1 ls "$id" 1>&2
        echo "${id}"
    done < <(grep "$SM" internal.txt | awk '{print $1 "_" $2 "_" $3 ".txt"}') > "test_${SM}.dat"
done
```

The rational of this code is: in a file called `internal.txt` I have a list of data that I need to separate in two groups, named **MB** and **BL**. I use `grep` to search for each of the groups, the I use `awk` to compose the basename of the file and it gets fed to the `while` loop as `id`. In that loop, I use `srun` to start a command (`ls` in this example) and as a result, I just output the `$id`.

The `internal.txt` file contains:

```
file 1 BL
file 1 MB
file 2 BL
file 2 MB
file 3 MB
```

So the expected output are two files, `test_BL.dat`:

```
file_1_BL.txt
file_2_BL.txt
```

and `test_MB.dat`:

```
file_1_MB.txt
file_2_MB.txt
file_3_MB.txt
```

But reality is that I get these two files... with nly the first line written, `test_BL.dat`:

```
file_1_BL.txt
```

and `test_MB.dat`:

```
file_1_MB.txt
```

I already know that `srun` is involved in the problem, because if I get rid of `srun` and leave only the `ls`, it works as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --output=test_%j.out
#SBATCH --error=test_%j.err
#SBATCH --workdir=.
#SBATCH --time=0:5:0
#SBATCH --partition=main
#SBATCH --qos=lowprio
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --requeue

for SM in MB BL
do
    while read -r id
    do
        ls "$id" 1>&2
        echo "${id}"
    done < <(grep "$SM" internal.txt | awk '{print $1 "_" $2 "_" $3 ".txt"}') > "test_${SM}.dat"
done
```

This last code works well, but now I'm missing the `srun`. Any ideas of what is happening here?

Note: the listed files exists.

Comment: Any chance srun reads from stdin? Perhaps you could try closing its stdin?

Comment: @Inian touchê! Closing *stdin* in `srun` prevented that behavior from occurring again. It looks like that `srun` reads its input to broadcast it to all subtasks it is starting. It is not waiting for anyone to read before reading itself, it just starts reading from the beginning... and discarding the data if the task finishes without having used the data. In short, adding the `srun` parameter `--input none` solves the issue. Wanna write an answer?

Comment: I have no idea what `srun` is and what it is used for. I think you could self explain and add an answer yourself with additional details to help future readers!

Comment: `srun` is, in short, the `mpirun` of SLURM (a resource manager, AKA queue system). It serves the purpose of spawning a binary over a set of nodes to start a parallel computation (os a sequential one, like in the example used in the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Inian, problem solved!

The trick is that `srun`, by default, reads its standard input to broadcast it to the different subprocesses that it is starting. It is not waiting for the subprocesses to start reading from the input, it just reads its input and keeps it in a buffer until someone reads or the processes finishes (and then the data is discarded).

To solve the problem at hand, we only have to close the standard input of srun. The easiest way to do this is to use the `--input` parameter by setting it to `none`:

```
srun --input none --job-name "Test-${id}" --nodes 1 --ntasks 1 --cpus-per-task 1 ls "$id" 1>&2
```

Closing the standard input by using the `bash` tools (i. e. adding `<&-`) or redirecting `/dev/null` to the standard input (`< /dev/null`) also work (tested).